# The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'

Tags: flutter

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {

var questions = [
{
'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
'answers': [
{'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
{'text': 'Red', 'score': 5},
{'text': 'Green', 'score': 3},
{'text': 'White', 'score': 1},
],
},
{
'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
'answers': [
{'text': 'Rabbit', 'score': 3},
{'text': 'Snake', 'score': 11},
{'text': 'Elephant', 'score': 5},
{'text': 'Lion', 'score': 9},
],
},
{
'questionText': 'Who\'s your favorite instructor?',
'answers': [
{'text': 'Max', 'score': 1},
{'text': 'Max', 'score': 1},
{'text': 'Max', 'score': 1},
{'text': 'Max', 'score': 1},
],
},
];

int questionIndex = 0;
void _AnswerQuestion (int score){

setState(() {

```
 questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
  if (questionIndex \< questions.length){
 print("We have more Qs"); 
}
```

});
}

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: Container(
child: questionIndex < questions.length ?
Quiz(QuestionIndex: questionIndex,answerQuesstion: _AnswerQuestion,questions: questions)
: Result()
),
);
}
}

when i added int score to _AnswerQuestion i got an error of "The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'" down in _AnswerQuestion i am new to flutter and following maximillian course[image]

Comment: Please reformat your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.  Easiest way to do that is to copy and paste your code and then surround it with  `\`\`\``.

Comment: At any rate, a `void Function(int)` (a function that requires an `int` argument) is not substitutable for a `void Function()` (a function that takes no arguments).  When invoked, where would the `int` argument come from?

Answer (score 1):

in ***quiz.dart*** change the type of answerQuestion to Function(int) like this

```
final Function(int) answerQuestion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add '?' in Function arguments. It will look like this
final Function? answerQuestion

Answer (score 0):

you can change voidcallback to Function

here is the code sample
instead of this

```
 final **VoidCallback** answerQuestion;
```

Use this

```
 final **Function** answerQuestion;
```